# How can i select a particular element(a picture in this case) of marquee tag and let the rest of pictures in marquee scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<marquee onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="start()">
<img src="img1.jpg">
<img src="img2.jpg">
<img src="img3.jpg">
</marquee>
```

> I want my program to hold the picture which is hovered at its place
>   and let the rest of the pictures scrolling on the back.  TIA

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag is deprecated, which means "not for use in new websites" — just fyi

Comment: oh, didn't know that. Thanks for the information but I'm not implementing this on any website but for some personal practice.

Comment: well its not possible with all three of them in the same `div`.split them into different divs and use css to align them, not sure if it will work or not.